# Zero matrix $M A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n*n},\quad \operatorname{rank}(A) = n $$

Is there a matrix $M$: $n\times n$ that will zero this matrix $M A = 0$, except for the zero matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{rank}(A)=n \implies A$ is invertible. Hence

$$ MA=0 \implies (MA)A^{-1}=0\cdot A^{-1}=0 \implies M=0. $$

Answer (score 2):

No. From $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ it follows that $A$ is surjective. Thus for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $Ax=y$. Now, $My=MAx=0$, thus $M=0$.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is useful to know is that $\dim\ker(AB)\leq\dim\ker(A)+\dim\ker B$ for all valid matrix multiplications (not necessarily of square matrices). In you case $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ means $\dim\ker(A)=0$, so it follows that $\dim\ker(MA)\leq\dim\ker(M)$ for all matrices$~M$. So $\ker(MA)$ can only be all of $\Bbb R^n$ if $\ker(M)$ is so as well, in other words if $M=0$ (this part of my argument does use that $A$ is square, so that both kernels live in spaces of the same dimension). This argument works for the opposite multiplication as well: $AM=0$ similarly implies $M=0$. Of course since $A$ is invertible here, you could do this more explicitly (see the other answers).